# My String becomes read only and will not concatenate

Tags: c#, string

I've got an issue here that's baffling me. I'm building a little multiplayer chatbox functionality in Unity. I post a message using the following function:

```
public void AddLine(string text)
{
    GetComponent<Text>().text += "\n" + text;
}
```

The problem here is that the code works perfectly until I connect to the chat server, and then the string refuses to concatenate further. I have verified with the debugger that the "text" parameter is passing good information to the function. As far as I can tell everything is perfectly fine, and yet it isn't.

As an aside, I'm encoding the text data to a byte array, shooting it up to the server, and then I have to decode it back to a string when it gets to the client. In the debugger the data returned from the server looks correct, and yet the program only breaks once it receives this data.

Is there anything about this byte encoding process that might mess my string up? The program is treating the string as if it doesn't exist, and yet in the debugger, it looks good.

Comment: Does it work if you *aren't* connected to the server? Say with some test data?

Comment: Well he says it does `The problem here is that the code works perfectly until I connect to the chat server`

Comment: @EricJ. I wasn't sure what he meant by "works perfectly" since presumably he doesn't get messages until he connects....

Comment: Perhaps the OP will comment on that.  My take is that he somehow tested the code before connecting to a chat server, and it worked then.

Comment: My working hypothesis is that there is some sort of extra garbage on this string that is screwing it up - something not visible in the debugger, as a relic of the encoding and decoding. When I use a regex on the string to clean it up, it works.

Answer (score 1):

OK I am able to answer my own question. Turns out that when you decode a string from a byte array, the string retains the length of the byte array. So the string just has a bunch of Nulls at the end of it that the debugger won't report.

Concatenating a string fails under this scenario.

Comment: how did you deal with it?

Comment: What do you mean by "when you decode a string from a byte array"? I'd expect that to mean `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray)`, but that wouldn't introduce unexpected `\0`s unless you were screwing up the byte array.

Comment: The byte array itself was too big. I was dealing with Steam's back end where you pass an In,Out byte array that gets filled with a Chat message in a binary format. So you pass in a byte array, which I had initialized to 2048 size, and I got out a byte array that was 2048, even though the message itself was only like 50 bytes or something. You can decode this to a string, but the function doesn't clean up the nulls for you. I solved the problem by truncating the byte array with string.Replace, replacing null characters with string.empty. that solved the issue.